# Why are table borders not collapsing when caption is positioned?

Tags: html, css

In this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jnddfyeq/ I have two tables with `border-collapse: collapse`. In the first one everything works as expected. In the second one I position the `caption` with `position: absolute` and now the borders between the `thead` and `tbody` do not collapse.

This happens in Firefox 38 and IE8 (not in a fiddle.) I have not tested other browsers. Is this behavior standard? If so why?

UPDATE: Same thing happens in Safari.

Comment: Really interesting find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really that the `borders` don't `collapse`. It seems that what's happening is that even if the `caption` is displayed out of the `table`, there is still an invisible `cell` being added to the `table`.

The specification mention that this can happen, it's not exactly clear what should happen in this case, but it's clear that a table follows a pretty strict layout structure and that it will compensate in the background when messing with that layout. See:

> Note. Positioning and floating of table cells can cause them not to be
>   table cells anymore, according to the rules in section 9.7. When
>   floating is used, the rules on anonymous table objects may cause an
>   anonymous cell object to be created as well.

Here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#table-layout

If you look at the computed style of your `absolute caption` you'll see it's not a `cell` anymore, so it's probably replaced by an `anonymous cell`. And I guess that since `table head` are always at the top by definition, this `anonymous cell` is placed automatically below it, in the `table body group`. If you set coordinates to 0, you'll see exactly where it ends up. And if you play with borders, you'll see also what happens.

See snippet:

```js
console.log('first caption:', window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByTagName('caption')[0]).display, '\nabsolute caption:',
window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByTagName('caption')[1]).display)
```

```css
body
{
    margin: 0;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    border-spacing: 12px;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
th {
    
    padding: 0.5em;
    border: 10px dotted green;
    background: #8cf;
   
    
}
td {
    
    padding: 0.5em;
    border: 15px dotted red;
    background: #8cf;
   
    
}
caption.abs {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; 
}
tr
{
    background-color: pink;
}
table.realnoncollapse {
    border-collapse: separate;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    border-spacing: 12px;
    background-color: yellow;
    
}
```

```html
<table>
    <caption>Chill Table</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr  id="tr1">
            <th>Chiller</th>
            <th>Chillness</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>The Dude</td>
            <td>Way chill</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>This Guy</td>
            <td>Pretty chill</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table>
    <caption class="abs">No chill</caption>
     
    <thead>
        <tr >
            <th>Chiller</th>
            <th>Chillness</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>The Dude</td>
            <td>Way chill</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>This Guy</td>
            <td>Pretty chill</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table class="realnoncollapse">
    
     <caption class="abs">No chill</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr >
            <th>Chiller</th>
            <th>Chillness</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>The Dude</td>
            <td>Way chill</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>This Guy</td>
            <td>Pretty chill</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```